# If there any methods to disabled Window key in electron js?

Tags: typescript, windows, electron, electron-vue

I've been working on developing an Online Examination System where it use to prevent students from cheating during the exam. I want to disable window key and other combination key like win + PrtSc..etc, but it didn't work.I have no ideas what to do!

If there any solutions or techniques you would suggest me to give it a try ?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it in electron, disabling OS keyboard shortcuts (including windows key, Ctrl+Alt+Del, Alt+Tab, etc.) requires very low-level interactions with OS. Basically you will have to write a C++ module and import it from JS. Even then, keep in mind that this behaviour is OS specific, so you will need different code if you need it to work on mac or linux. Also some bindings like Ctrl+Alt+Del, if you don't want them on, are very hard to disable even in C++. Basically good luck achieving this in electron